# Problem with date based relationship in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, date, relationship

I build a one-to-one relationship within rails with a date based condition, which means only the order of today should be returned.

```
  has_one :todays_order, :through => :patient_orders, :source => :daily_order ,:conditions => ["order_for_date = ?", Date.current]
```

Lets say for yesterday there is a todays order but today there should be no todays order because there doesn't exist a order with a date equal to the date of today.

This only happens when I call a controller and get a json response with that data included. 
If i try to reproduce that within the console it behaves right and gives me `nil` as value of todays order.
My environment is development.

Another curious thing is, that after a server restart the todays order will returned right, so it seems that there is something like caching active. Could that be?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to [load your association query passing it a true value](http://railsguides.heroku.com/2.3.5/association_basics.html#controlling-caching):

```
# Example
@course_orders.todays_order(true)
```

Or you can try wrapping the query in this kind of block:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.uncached do
  your query
end
```

or forcing the cache to clear:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.query_cache.clear_query_cache
```

Comment: and how can i do that when I'm rendering json? e.g.  `respond_with(@course_orders, :include => :orders)`

Comment: The problem is the query that generates @course_orders it should be something along the lines of: @course_orders.todays_order(true)